# Database Without a database? [Advice needed]

Tags: database, database-design

For a school project we need to store a lot of weather data. 8000 rows per second are supposed to be inserted. This data also needs to be queried fast, with filters, groups, sorting and limiting.

But we are not allowed to use an existing database management system like mySql or Mongo.

Currently we are thinking about creating a new file every second with 8000 lines each. Only reading the data back from all those files to generate a top 10 list would not be fast. So fast querying is the main problem.

Any recommendations are welcome.

EDIT:

We need to store 8000 rows per second containing the following values from from xml files we receive. We already can parse and store 8000 of these xml files per second in flat files(CSV style). But we are not able to do any fast querying. An example query would be: Get the highest 100 temperatures from the latest 8 million rows.

```
<MEASUREMENT>
    <STN>123456</STN>
    <DATE>2009-09-13</DATE>
    <TIME>15:59:46</TIME>
    <TEMP>-60.1</TEMP>
    <DEWP>-58.1</DEWP>
    <STP>1034.5</STP>
    <SLP>1007.6</SLP>
    <VISIB>123.7</VISIB>
    <WDSP>10.8</WDSP>
    <PRCP>11.28</PRCP>
    <SNDP>11.1</SNDP>
    <FRSHTT>010101</FRSHTT>
    <CLDC>87.4</CLDC>
    <WNDDIR>342</WNDDIR>
</MEASUREMENT>
```

Comment: So is the assignment to build your own database management system?

Comment: That's what it boils down to.

Comment: yes, querying the data in an fast way is our main problem.

Comment: What kind of school / curriculum would that be ?

Comment: yes precisely.  The Hanze University in Groningen, we also do not know why we are not allowed to use a database. We think that they want us to cache all example queries while we import the data.

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't include "hotbackup" in the requirements list too.  On a more serious note, it may be the case that they want you to fail no matter what you try, and understand the why of every failed attempt you tried.

Comment: "queried fast" doesn't mean anything in particular--it's not a practical specification. Would you sign a contract to deliver that according to your client's interpretation or hand over money for a product if all you knew was it "queried fast"? Get some hard numbers for architecture & patterns of querying.

Answer (score 0):

How about using SQLite? You can embed it in your Project and tweak for performance.
Also I would check here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

Comment: Sorry we are not allowed any existing database systems. including SQLite and NoSQL etc..

Answer (score 0):

Try out clickhouse (https://clickhouse.yandex/) :)
It's kinda overkill, but it will work very fast!

edit:
  You are not allowed use ANY database? If so, than use flat files.

Comment: Yes. Flat files are basically the only option. but querying by reading all the files is really slow. Any recommendations on how we can do a fast flat file query on large files?

Comment: @TimoStrating, What language are you using?

Comment: free of choice, our group is already experienced with the following languages (java, c, go, javascript)

Comment: @TimoStrating, You can use "Smart" file names and reorganize them based on data from 3rd party. It will be easier to search. Can you add some information what information you got and what filters you will use?

Comment: I added an example of one of the problems we are currently are trying to tackle in the post.

Comment: @TimoStrating, What free space on your disk you got? :) You can use multiple folders and emulate B-Tree.